# SETLOCAL on PATH environment variable does not work

Tags: command-line, batch-file, environment-variables

I have a batch file that needs to have a different PATH environment variable to the rest of the machine. After a bit of googling, using "SETLOCAL" should change a variable in the batch script, and as soon as it ends it is chnaged back, so my script is:

```
SETLOCAL
set PATH="C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin;"

qmake project.pro
```

And I get the output:

```
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Even though qmake is at the path "C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin\qmake.exe", and ruinning

```
C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin\qmake.exe
```

from the command line works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
set PATH="C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin"
```

but better:

```
set "PATH=%path%;C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin"
```

If you set the path to set `"C:\Qt\4.8.1\bin;"`  the semi colon is included in the `path` as part of a valid folder name.